# Running Electron app on Linux mint 19.3 without GUI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-interface, linux-mint

I would like to use Linux Mint 19.3 on a terminal and need to run Electron app on it but I would not like to have GUI options like bottom menu, desktop icons etc.

Does anyone know any GUI that could be used for this purpose (because LightDM has bottom menu etc.)?

Or in the worst case, I would need a way to completely hide the bottom menu.